# simpleLoginTool giving me "Error: The specified authentication type is not enabled for this Firebase" when I try to register new user

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, yeoman-generator-angular, firebasesimplelogin

I am creating an AngularJS, Yeoman stack with Firebase, AngularFire application and I used generator-angularfire (https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire) to set up my simpleLoginTools. I only downloaded the email/password verification as the only point for authentication is that I need a few users for Admin purposes to create new and destroy old content for the site. However, when I go to my 'example.com/#/login' and try to register for a new user via email and password it gives me a

```
Error: The specified authentication type is not enabled for this Firebase.
```

Is it because I don't have an User model in my application/Firebase database? If so how do I go about creating one? If not how do I get past this error?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you enable the "Email & Password" authentication provider in the Forge (administrative control panel) of your Firebase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen lols actually, no I did not. My first time using angularjs and firebase, didn't even see the tab on the side in the Firebase database manager. Thank you sir, plus one for being awesome and fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing the answer here because i was written down in the comments. 
This is happening because u have not enabled password authentication in firebase.

In order to do so you have to go the section Login and Auth and at the end you will se Enable Email and Password Authentication
[image]

Comment: does this need time to propagate ? because I have enabled this in the console (its the only auth method I have enabled) but I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Yeah I'm experiencing the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this topic, using **firebase SDK 2.x** (for example wih angularfire2) but created **a new app on the Google console**, from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499239/4717408):

> Firebase2 in its current version (2.4.2) is not yet compatible with
>   Firebase SDK v3, and all projects created with the new Firebase
>   console are only accessible with calls comaptible with SDK v3.
>
> You want to create your Firebase backend in the legacy console
>   [www.firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com/) first, and then migrate to the new console.
>
> This is documented in this closed issue of the angularfire2 github:
>   https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/189

Taking an app from the old console and migrating it to the new console worked for me.