# Angularfire 2 Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple sample auth app with Ionic 2 and angularfire 2 as backend, when i try to create new user it says:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The specified
>   authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.

But i already enabled firebase authentication in firebase console:[image]

**app.ts**

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase, firebaseAuthConfig, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    defaultFirebase('https://samplequizapp-50eb5.firebaseio.com'),
    firebaseAuthConfig({
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password
    })
  ],
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  user: any = {};
  data: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.af.database.list('/userId')
  }

  signUp(data) {
    this.af.auth.createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    })
  }

}
```

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my code:

Comment: It looks like you are using the 'new' Firebase. It may be related to Angularfire2 not being ready for this yet, according to the readme on Github: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#angularfire2-is-currently-not-on-new-firebase-30-sdk-but-there-is-an-update-in-progress

Comment: I somewhoe deleted the last part of my original comment. I was getting the same message, but was trying to use AngularFire 1.x connecting to new Firebase. I captured the JSON of the entire error I was receiving and it had this: "Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/" so I realised I was using the wrong library. But it looks like 2.x isn't quite ready yet? Maybe you could try standard (i.e. non-AngularFire) auth as per the SDK reference in that error message in the meantime??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firebase2 in its current version (2.4.2) is not yet compatible with Firebase SDK v3, and all projects created with the new Firebase console are only accessible with calls comaptible with SDK v3.

You want to create your Firebase backend in the legacy console [www.firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com) first, and then migrate to the new console.

This is documented in this closed issue of the angularfire2 github: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/189