# Authentication failure Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

Using Angular Fire 1.2.0 I am creating a login page to enter into Firebase database using Email and password authentication.I have created following controller:

```
controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope',"$firebaseAuth",function($scope,$firebaseAuth){

var firebaseObj=new Firebase("https://first-project-3c9ef.firebaseio.com/");
var auth = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);
$scope.user={};
$scope.SignIn=function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var username=$scope.user.email;
    var password=$scope.user.password;
    auth.$authWithPassword({
        email:username,
        password:password
    })
    .then(function(authData){
        console.log("Authentication successful");
    },function(error){
        console.log("Authentication failure",error);
    });
}

}]);
```

Even on entering right credentials console is giving authentication failure.
I have already enabled sign in method as Email and password authentication in my Firebase account,even then it is showing Authentication Failure.
I am following latest guide of Angular fire.

Comment: Most likely this is because you created your project in the new Firebase Console. Projects created in the new Firebase Console only work with the new SDK. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481731/ . Luckily AngularFire 2.0 was just released, which works with the latest SDK release. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

Comment: thanks it works well with old console